# Does Torrent traffic to NAS go through my laptop?

Tags: networking, router, utorrent

If I am running utorrent on my laptop but direct the download file to go to my NAS that is hard wired to the router (Linksys E3000) is the traffic still directed to my laptop then uploaded wirelessly to my NAS or will it be sent directly from my router to my NAS?

I really wish my Buffalo Linkstation had a bit torrent client built in but it doesn't.  I hate to spent the money on another one that does.

Comment: After some research I figured out that I would need an NAS with a built in torrent client if I didn't want to be using my laptop's bandwidth to transfer the files to my NAS.  I broke down and ordered a new NAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the data will be going through your laptop.

The program that's controlling the download is running on your laptop so the data *has* to go through it.

It won't be written to the laptop's hard drive first, the client should write it directly to the NAS drive.

Comment: I opened up the Wireless Network Connection Status to see how much traffic was going through my wireless card.  Sure enough it was coming down and right back up to the NAS.

Answer (score 1):

The data will be downloaded from the internet to your laptop, then your laptop will write the data to the hard drive.  The fact that the drive is over the network doesn't really matter to windows.

You would need either a router, or a NAS that can act as the torrent client.

Answer (score 0):

It's still sent through your laptop.  Your torrent application handles all the communication and the writing of the downloaded files to a disk.  Since the app runs on your laptop, it all has to go there first.

There is open-source firmware available for most consumer-grade routers that allows you to add extra functionality.  Check out:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_E3000

If your router supports usb you may be able to install a bit torrent client (transmission) directly on your router using [optware](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Optware) combined with the modified firmware, but this is a pretty advanced operation.

Personally, even though my router supports it, I just have a desktop box that is on all the time and runs [transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/).  Then I use a [transmission remote gui](http://code.google.com/p/transmisson-remote-gui/) to manage the torrents from my laptop.  I feel like running a bt client on your router is a bit beyond its intended capabilities and I'd rather have a stable internet connection.

Comment: I have looked into the dd-wrt but I'm not interested in modifying my router.  It works exactly the way I want it to without doing that.  I just wanted to get around it having to come to my machine then to the NAS.  I decided to buy an NAS with a built in torrent client.